# How to get syntax highlighting for alternate file extension for Visual Studio 2010 or 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

For older version of Visual Studio it was a simple tweak in registry

http://codebetter.com/darrellnorton/2004/04/21/get-visual-studio-syntax-highlighting-for-alternate-file-extensions/

But for Visual Studio 2010+ the same key doesn't exist in registry so how to do it now ?

Comment: Use Tools + Options, Text Editor, File Extension.  Type the extension string, pick the editor, click Add.  Look around some more, this was supposed to be discoverable.

Comment: Right-click, open with, set as default, from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28374140/492

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension` and type your alternative extension and then associate it with your editor (e.g. `Microsoft Visual C++`)

Comment: This is not helpful for customized syntax.

Comment: Change appears to work only if file is closed and re-opened.