# Edit .SASS file as .CSS and .SCSS on visual Studio?

Tags: syntax, configuration, sass, edit, visual-studio-2017

anyone knows how I set VS2017 up to edit .SASS files like .SCSS and .CSS files with highlighted syntax? I couldn't find any solution so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25319912/3058802)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get syntax highlighting for alternate file extension for Visual Studio 2010 or 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499143/how-to-get-syntax-highlighting-for-alternate-file-extension-for-visual-studio-20)